# Spring integration ending the flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am working on a spring integration project, currently we are using return null to end the flow in some instances. Generally return null is not a good practice, I am looking for an alternate. I tried with throwing exception for stopping the flow which i believed better than returning null. But in some cases there are two flows from single publish-subscribe-channel, in those cases throwing exception stops both the flow.Is there any better way to stop the flow in SI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said: return `null`. There is the way to route by some condition (the same you decide to return `null`)  to the Outbound Channel Adapter what is a one-way component and therefore end of the flow. But this is going to be too wordy. Although in the future you will have a flexibility to do anything else in this `null` case.

Right, the exception way may cause unexpected behavior especially when you have a logic after first call, like in your publish-subscribe case. But still you can do that when you use an executor with that channel.

Comment: Hi Artem Bilan, thanks for responding. Yes we tried with the executor and it works, but adding an executor adds additional complexity especially when the service is very simple and straight forward. I was thinking if there is something like end-channel where we can route the message and end the flow or direct SI method call to explicitly end the flow. In that case it would be more expressive to read and understand the code as well.

Comment: Yes, there is such a channel and it is called `nullChannel`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-special-channels. But you still need a routing logic to go that way. To return `null` from the service method to stop the flow is much easier.

Comment: returning null for now just using the name to the null object like 'return THIS_NULL_OBJEC_STOPS_THE_FLOW' to make it more expressive.

Comment: @ArtemBilan is there way to detect the flow is ended? Actually, I have defined many step in the flow but final return is null. I also want to have a count for null return.